# Front end ssl implementation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ssl, https

So I'm trying to set up a secure connection between my client app and server.

I'm running an express server using the HTTPS node module on the backend and running a React app on the front end.

I've implemented the back end certifications with `https.createServer` method with a key and certificate. Do I need to implement anything with my React code? Or are all api calls done through js automatically encrypted via the browser?

Can't seem to find any information on implementing SSL for React on the front end so I am assuming things are handled automatically by the browser.

Also wanted to make sure for the sake of security that all content across an SSL, from browser to client and from client to browser is secured?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your 'React code' you specify the URL for your API end-point. If it starts with 'http://' the communication is not encrypted, if it starts with 'https://' it will be encrypted.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://yourdomain.com/api/resource`) 
        .then(result=> {
            this.setState({items:result.json()});
        });
}
```